# Error in hist.default(data) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram in R but I get the following: Error in hist.default(data) : 'x' must be numeric

I'm using the function hist(data). Can anyone help me resolve the issue?

Please see the attachment below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaSbN.png)

Comment: Could you provide your data with `dput()`, not a photo?

Comment: **Note:** Please read our tutorial on how to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) before posting next time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`hist` expects a `numeric` vector. If you use `hist(data)`, `hist` gets the whole dataset and doesn't know what to do with it.

You should use the `$` operator to get a single column from that dataset.

```r
hist(data$height)
hist(data$weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if you made a mistake when reading in the data. `read.csv` should work. (BTW, height and weight appear to be confused in your data!)

```
dat <- read.csv('./unit_3_test_data')

hist(dat$height)
hist(dat$weight)
hist(dat)
```

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 50
set.seed(42)
tmp <- data.frame(
  height=rnorm(n, 180, 20),
  weight=rnorm(n, 70, 3)
)
write.csv(tmp, 'unit_3_test_data', row.names=F, quote=F)
```